# Magento connect manager showing blank page

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am running a magento site but when i click on magento connect manager. it displays blank page. i have enabled error mode but it doesn't show any error or no log as well

Answer (score 0):

You have another option , paste the extension key in below link and get the extensions files and install it manually :

http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php

Answer (score 0):

Whenever this happens the first thing I check is the **PHP memory limit**.

Magento overrides the normal error handler with it's own, but when the error is "Out of memory" that custom handler cannot run, so nothing is seen.

**And Other Suggestion**

I was also facing this error. The error has been fixed by changing content of core function getRowUrl in app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php The core function is :

```
public function getRowUrl($item) 
{
$res = parent::getRowUrl($item); 
$res = parent::getRowUrl($item); 
}
```

Replaced with :

```
public function getRowUrl($item) 
{
return $this->getUrl(’*/*/edit’, array(’id’ => $item->getId())); 
}
```